# Allow Windows Server 2016 user account to run Scheduled Task that was set up to run as another account

Tags: windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

I've created a Scheduled Task via `schtasks.exe` so that it runs as an elevated account **[A]**. However, my reduced privilege account **[B]** can't manually trigger the task to run through the Task Scheduler or via the CLI.

I have tried:

- Changing the permissions for the the file in `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` to allow **[B]** account to read and execute. This apparently works in Server 2008, but it didn't seem to work in Server 2016.
- Pulled the permissions from the Registry to inspect, but could not edit the Registry SDDL for the task to overwrite the Registry.
- Switched to PowerShell `Register-ScheduledJob` and associated `Start-Job`, but still doesn't allow the **[B]** account to trigger the Scheduled Job or Scheduled Task

My intent is to allow the restricted account **[B]** to run a process without allowing direct access to the files that are ACL restricted to the elevated **[A]** account. The process needs to run with **[A]** permissions to access the files and pass the selected data back to process running with **[B]** permissions.

Note - I'm guessing that I should set up a Service to do this, but I'm trying to do it in scripting. If you have a good example of setting up a System Service, I'll take that as well!

Thanks! :)